# Rails server down when job sends order mailer with pdf attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq, wicked-pdf

After the user command is paid, I want to send confirmation email(I'm using Mandrill, if it helps). One of these confirmations involves gift cards when a user purchases a gift card for someone else.

I want to attach the gift card (pdf format) to this email.

Here is the corresponding code in my mailer:

```
def confirmation_cmd_gift_card(commande)
  @commande = commande
  @gift_card = GiftCard.find_by(commande_id: commande.id)

  mail(to: @commande.user.email, subject: " Un grand merci pour votre commande !") do |format|
    format.html
    format.text
    format.pdf do 
      attachments["carte_cadeau_pennarbox.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string(
          pdf: 'carte_cadeau_pennarbox',
          encoding: 'UTF-8',
          template: 'order_notifier/carte_cadeau_pennarbox.pdf.erb',
          layout: 'cc_pdf.html',
          disposition: 'attachment'
        )
      )
    end
  end
end
```

A background job(Sidekiq) performs the task of sending email(works for other kind of emails).

It seems that my rails server stops when the job performs the gift card email sending. Here are the logs:

```
Rendered order_notifier/carte_cadeau_pennarbox.pdf.erb within layouts/cc_pdf.html (19.2ms)
"***************[\"/Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf\", \"-q\", \"file:////var/folders/2k/r8df_vt57qbcj2s3w5p4nty40000gn/T/wicked_pdf20180626-47763-v7znb.html\", \"/var/folders/2k/r8df_vt57qbcj2s3w5p4nty40000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20180626-47763-1pmlnk.pdf\"]***************"
```

It doesn't look like an error... Something is happening and is breaking my rails server but i can't figure out why.

Do you have any tips?

Comment: It would be worth clarifying what you mean by your rails server being "down" and "stops" and "breaking". Does the rails server exit and stop running, does it seem to hang and stop processing anything (but is still running)?

Comment: sorry. yes the rails server hangs

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems before with `rails server` hanging when using wicked_pdf.

This has been because by default the rails server is single threaded.

The sequence of events is (I think):

1. The background job requests a page from the server in order to render it as PDF
2. The page includes some assets
3. wicked_pdf asks for the assets from the server
4. The server is still processing the request for a page so cannot respond
5. wicked_pdf waits patiently (you may get a timeout eventually).

Of course while that is all happening your app is unresponsive too as all the requests from browsers join the queue.

The way I got it to work in this case was to use puma locally and to make sure it had multiple threads to handle incoming requests.

Comment: As an aside: ultimately I ended up rendering the content outside of a HTTP request because of issues like this.

Comment: @justinedps26 It works fine in production, because you have multiple web workers, so the building of the pdf is not blocked as described above. Using Puma or Unicorn with multiple workers in your dev environment will alleviate the problem, or you can replace web requesting content in your PDF with pre-rendered content.